# How to put JSON data into a HTML div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Here is my problem: I want to put JSON data that I catch with an Ajax call in an HTML div.

```js
function showEspece(espece, categorie, object) {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'getespece.php',
    data: {
      espece: espece,
      categorie: categorie
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#output').html(data); //what i try to do but don't work
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

And here is what the variable data contains:

[image]

How can I show the variable's content in an HTML div - in a table particularly?

Comment: use JSON.stringify function

Comment: You probably need to stringify the data first. `$('#outpu't).html(JSON.stringify(data))`.

Comment: whith stringify it looks like that : {"NOMA":["Chachi","Rafiki","Chakra"],"SEXE":["F","M","F"],"DATENAISSANCE":["05-MAY-15","07-JAN-15","17-SEP-17"]} and it's not really readable by everybody

Comment: Yes but it's the most readable form you can have a JSON.

Comment: use JSON.stringify(data,null,4) to pretty-print the output with a 4 spaces indentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pre` tag to display JSON.

```js
var data = {"NOMA":["Chachi","Rafiki","Chakra"],"SEXE":["F","M","F"],"DATENAISSANCE":["05-MAY-15","07-JAN-15","17-SEP-17"]};
$('pre').html(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data variable it's a JS object you need to convert it to string or the format you want to show it before calling $('#output').html(data).
You can do something like:

```
function showEspece(espece, categorie, object) 
  {
    $.ajax({           
      type : 'POST',                           
      url: 'getespece.php',                  
      data: {espece: espece, categorie: categorie },                       
      dataType: 'json',                     
      success: function(data)          
      {
        console.log(data);
        data = JSON.stringify(data)     
        $('#output').html(data); //what i try to do but don't work
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

as your json data children are array you can use $.each function:

Example:

```
var noma = data.NOMA;
var html_append = '';
$.each(noma, function(key,value) {
   html_append += value +'<br>';
});

$('#output').html(html_append);
```

The same code you can use for also data.DATENAISSANCE and data.SEXE

Answer (score 0):

Since your data returned is already in a JSON format, i suggest you to use $.getJSON and change your $_POST by $_GET variables in your getespece.php.

Also, your JSON Objects seems to be kind of not formatted correctly.. If you want to display your "especes" in an HTML table, the right JSON format could be something like this:

```
{
    "Columns": [
        "DateDeNaissance",
        "Nom",
        "Sexe"
    ],
    "Especes": [{
        "DateDeNaissance": "05-MAY-15",
        "Nom": "Chachi",
        "Sexe": "F"
    }, {
        "DateDeNaissance": "07-JAN-15",
        "Nom": "Rafiki",
        "Sexe": "M"
    }, {
        "DateDeNaissance": "17-SEP-17",
        "Nom": "Chakra",
        "Sexe": "F"
    }]
}
```

Once you have this output from your PHP, change your JS to this:

```
$.getJSON("getespece.php", {
    espece: espece,
    categorie: categorie
})
.done(function(json) {
    // Build the html Table
    var html = "<table>\n";
        html += "<thead>\n";
        html += "<tr>\n";
    // Columns
    $.each(json.Columns, function(k, value) {
        html += "<th>" + column + "</th>\n";
    });
    html += "</tr>\n";
    html += "<tbody>\n";
    // Rows
    $.each(json.Especes, function(column, values) {
        html += "<tr>\n";
        // Cells
        $.each(values, function(k, val) {
            html += "<td>" + val + "</td>\n";
        });
        html += "</tr>\n";
    });
    html += "</tbody>\n";
    html += "</table>\n";
    $("#output").html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = {
    DATENAISSANCE: [...],
    ...
}

var root = document.getElementById("output");
var table = element("table");
root.appendChild(table);

var dataName;
for (dataName in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(dataName)) {
        var row = element("tr", element("th", dataName));
        data[dataName].forEach(function (dataValue) {
            row.appendChild(element("td", dataValue));
        });
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
}


// Create a convenient function `element` which creates an element and sets its content
function element(nodeName, content, attributes, eventListeners) {
    var node = document.createElement(nodeName);
    appendChildren(node, content);
    return node;
}

function appendChildren(node, content) {
    var append = function (t) {
        if (/string|number/.test(typeof t)) {
            node.innerHTML += t;
        } else if (t instanceof HTMLElement) {
            node.appendChild(t);
        }
    };
    if (content instanceof Array) {
        content.forEach(function (item) {
            append(item);
        });
    } else {
        append(content);
    }
}
```